# How can I transform the coordinates of a Shapefile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gis, postgis, shapefile

I am trying to get neighborhood data into my application, and I'm having problems with the data I am using, which I got from [here](http://gispub02.sfgov.org/website/sfshare/catalog/realtor_neighborhoods.zip).

This file contains a shapefile that has the neighborhoods of San Francisco.  I am running a Ruby on Rails framework, and I'm currently using [GeoRuby](https://github.com/nofxx/georuby) to parse the shapefile.

The code looks like this:

```
def self.run_import
  shpfile = '/path/to/realtor_neighborhoods/realtor_neighborhoods'
  ShpFile.open(shpfile) do |shp|
    shp.each do |shape|
      # This gets the first (and only) Polygon from each MultiPolygon
      polygon = shape.geometry.geometries.first 
      puts polygon.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

The code is able to parse the file, but I am unable to understand the coordinates as interpreted.  All of the points have values in the millions, when I would expect coordinates between -180 and 180, for valid latitude and longitude. Take a look at an example point:

```
<GeoRuby::SimpleFeatures::Point:0x00000104566a08 @srid=4326, @with_z=false, \
   @with_m=false, @x=6015402.9999795845, @y=2114960.4999904726, @z=0.0, @m=0.0>,
```

What is the format of these coordinate values?  How can I convert them to values that are meaningful to me? (i.e. latitude/longitude based on the SRID 4326 <=>  WGS84 spatial reference system)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data you have from the shape file is [projected geographic data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection).

From your question it sounds like you would really just prefer to have your data in lat/long. To get that you need to reproject your data. I am not a ruby guy, but a quick web search reveals that georuby does not support reprojection http://georuby.rubyforge.org/, however [rgeo](http://rubygems.org/gems/rgeo) does. http://www.daniel-azuma.com/blog/archives/28

If you would like to know more about map projections have a look [here](http://earth.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=22373&topic=23750&answer=148111).

By the way there is a stackexchange site for GIS (geographic information systems) experts called http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: More specifically, you need to transform via Proj.4 http://virtuoso.rubyforge.org/rgeo/RGeo/CoordSys/Proj4.html

Comment: Thank you so much, and I've been trying to test this out for a full day now.  I can't actually test it yet because now I've run into this:
https://github.com/dazuma/rgeo/issues/6  
Hopefully, I can work around that and then accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this is still getting a log of views.  I ended up struggling with RGeo, but there's another solution.  If you are able/willing to do your conversion outside/before you execute your ruby code, check out ogr2ogr.

There are more details in my comment on the bottom here:
[How Can I Use (Ruby) RGeo to Transform (Unproject) Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006581/how-can-i-use-ruby-rgeo-to-transform-unproject-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question as I wanted to transform points supplied in a Shapefile from OSGB36 British National Grid format to WGS84 format (decimal degrees). I spent a lot of time figuring this out so hopefully this code will prove useful.

This code uses the [ffi-ogr](https://github.com/scooterw/ffi-ogr) gem and requires the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) library:

```ruby
require 'ffi-ogr'

data = OGR.read file_name
new_spatial_ref = OGR.import_sr(4326, 'epsg')

data.layers.each do |layer|
  transformer = OGR::CoordinateTransformation.find_transformation(layer.spatial_ref, new_spatial_ref)

  layer.features.each do |feature|
    geometry = OGR::Tools.cast_geometry(feature.geometry)
    geometry.transform(transformer)

    # Do something with geometry here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: wanted to convert projected geodata to Lat/Long values.

The ogr2ogr tool was much easier to use than I expected.

To install:

`apt-get install gdal-bin`

Get info about your shapefile:

`ogrinfo data.shp -al -so`

Convert to Lat/Long and JSON:

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs WGS84 data.json data.shp`

Comment: I am trying with the same command above but getting an error of unable to open, i have only shape file does it need .shx and .dbf too.