# How Can I Use (Ruby) RGeo to Transform (Unproject) Coordinates

Tags: ruby, coordinates, gis, coordinate-systems, proj

I started with [How can I transform the coordinates of a Shapefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963991/how-can-i-transform-the-coordinates-of-a-shapefile) .

The response there started me on [what I think is] the right track, but I still haven't been able to solve my problem.

One issue is that I haven't found the correct projection yet: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13330/how-can-i-correctly-transform-unproject-from-lcc

EDIT: That question on the gis site has been answered, and I was able to reproduce a correct transformation using the PROJ command line tool cs2cs.   It looks like this:

```
larry$  cs2cs -f "%.8f" +proj=lcc +lat_1=37.06666666666667 +lat_2=38.43333333333333 +lat_0=36.5 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=500000.0000000002 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs +to +proj=lonlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84
6011287.4999795845 2100857.2499904726
-122.40375492   37.74919006 0.00000000
```

Now, that I had the correct transformation, I was able to try the same thing in a simple form using RGeo:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 >     projection_str = ' +proj=lcc +lat_1=37.06666666666667 +lat_2=38.43333333333333 +lat_0=36.5 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=500000.0000000002 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs'
 => " +proj=lcc +lat_1=37.06666666666667 +lat_2=38.43333333333333 +lat_0=36.5 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=500000.0000000002 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 >     projection = RGeo::CoordSys::Proj4.new(projection_str)
 => #<RGeo::CoordSys::Proj4:0x805cba18 " +proj=lcc +lat_1=37.06666666666667 +lat_2=38.43333333333333 +lat_0=36.5 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=500000.0000000002 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 >     desired_str = '+proj=lonlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84'
 => "+proj=lonlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 >     desired = RGeo::CoordSys::Proj4.new(desired_str)
 => #<RGeo::CoordSys::Proj4:0x805271ac " +proj=lonlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 >     RGeo::CoordSys::Proj4::transform_coords(projection, desired, 6011287.4999795845, 2100857.2499904726 )
 => [-140.92282523143973, 30.16981659183029]
```

1. Why are the results different between RGeo and cs2cs?
2. Once I can make RGeo perform the correct translation, is there a way I can create the proper factory to transform a complete Geometry instead of a point?
3. Is there a command-line tool I can use as a workaround to transform all of the points in my shapefile so that I can move on with my life?

In general: Would someone please instruct me on how to properly use this library?

Thank you so much for looking.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this with RGeo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a wild stab in the dark, because I don't know RGeo or even Ruby, try substituting your coordinates in feet with their metres equivalent: 1832244.0944819663048746863094224, 640342.57048223700783128534419392 (you probably won't need that number of decimal places though...) Another possibility is to swap the coordinates around - maybe RGeo makes some unconventional assumptions.

If you are able to call executables from Ruby, you could simply use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to convert your shapefiles.

Comment: Mersey.  You are my hero.  If you live anywhere near San Francisco, I want to buy you a beer or 7.  Here's what worked:

1. Modify the supplied .prj file from LambertConformal_Conic to Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP - (Credit goes to Frank Warmerdam http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/ERROR-6-No-translation-for-Lambert-Conformal-Conic-to-PROJ-4-format-is-known-td2568835.html)
2. ogr2ogr -s_srs realtor_neighborhoods.prj -t_srs EPSG:4326 ./output.shp  realtor_neighborhoods.shp

Comment: Pay for my flight from the UK, and you have a deal! :) Glad you managed to get it working.